# why it throws java.lang.classCastException

Tags: java, stack

this is my class and I want to sort my stack but it will throw an exception please help me thanks!

```
public class jj {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stack<Integer> s = new ImplimentingAStackUsingAnArrayOfAGivenSizeN(5);
        s.push(1);
        s.push(3);
        s.push(5);
        s.push(2);
        s.push(4);
        Collections.sort((List<Integer>) (s));
        System.out.println(s);
        while (!s.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(s.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

the stack traces:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
datastructurechapter5.ImplimentingAStackUsingAnArrayOfAGivenSizeN 
cannot be cast to java.util.List at datastructurechapter5.jj.main(jj.java:24)  
   `Collections.sort((List<Integer>) (s));`
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: Is the `Stack` a interface or class of your own? What happens if you do: `java.util.Stack<Integer> s = new ImplimentingAStackUsingAnArrayOfAGivenSizeN(5);` instead?

Comment: OT: It's "implement" (with an 'e'), not "impliment" (with an 'i'). But that's not why you're having trouble (I'm assuming you've used the same spelling throughout your code).

Answer (score 5):

I'd assume you are using (and extending) a wrong `Stack`. Make sure you have

```
import java.util.Stack;
```

If the `Stack` is some class of yours, you'd have to define it to impelement `List`:

```
public class Stack implements List {..}
```

But that would be a lot of work, so use `java.util.Stack`

Note: As Jesper commented, you'd better use [`java.util.Deque`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) (perhaps `ArrayDeque`)

Comment: Note that `java.util.Stack` is a legacy collection class, its documentation recommends using `java.util.Deque` instead.